# Revit API C# - ShowElements of ViewSheet, Select ViewPort, Activate Viewport works during Debug Step through but not live

Tags: revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I'm trying to activate a viewport using [Jeremy's Keys](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/11/launching-a-revit-command.html) on a sheet and I am able to do it while doing Debug Step-Through but for some reason, it doesn't work when live.

I've tried the following:

1) using a while loop to wait for the active view to be the viewport's view but it doesn't seem to fire.

2) putting it in a separate transaction

3) tried using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);`

4) started looking into Async, await however I'm not that skilled with it yet.

Has anyone else come across this issue and found a solution?

My current Sudo code is similar to the title of the question.

`draw a temporary line across viewport`

`doc.showElements(temporaryline)`

`delete temporary line`

`Select viewport`

`Press.Keys("AV")` (AV is my shortcut for activating a view when the viewport is selected)

I can upload actual code if needed

////////////////UPDATE/////////////////
**here is the culprit**

```
//change views to sheet
uidoc.ShowElements(viewportElement); 


//select viewport
uidoc.Selection.SetElementIds(elementIdsViewPort);

//activate viewport
Press.Keys("AV");
```

Comment: You should be able to do this - although you may need to use an External Event. If it written in Python, could you post your code?

Comment: @Callum, could you speak more on the external event or provide an example? My code is written in C#.

Comment: @Callum, I've updated the question to show the code. feel free to try it on your end. I've found that If I comment out the `showElements` line and already have the sheet open, the viewport will activate.

Comment: Nope Im stumped. In Python you can use `System.Windows.Forms` `SendKeys` to do all sorts of stuff like this, but it doesnt seem to trigger Revits hotkeys. You can set up a timer, then click on a Parameter input field or start a Text note and have a timer input 'AV' as if its a user pressing the keys ... but if you have a viewport selected, it doesnt register. Strange!

Comment: @Callum, very strange indeed. thanks for looking into it. I've made a bit of headway into it using Async / Await methods. I'm now able to change views and then zoom extents of view which is nice. Cheers to "building the car as you're driving it"

Comment: Got it working with Async/await Tasks. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ [this post helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089417/c-sharp-wait-until-condition-is-true)

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that possibly Revit will do nothing at all to activate the view as long as your add-in is active. You need to relinquish control back to Revit in able for it to be able to do anything at all. Revit is single-threaded, and the add-in hogs the single thread. I believe.

Comment: Interesting. After more testing, if it goes without stepping through, it seems to work maybe 2 out of 5 times the way I want it to. if I step through, it works every time. It seems like I need a way of slowing down the process but also needing it to not freeze. Something like a pause button.